# Split a vector into parts of size n

Tags: matlab

I want to split a vector `v` in parts of size `n` and obtain the indexes (`idx`) that define these parts. Example, `v = [2 1 4 6], n=2, idx =[1 1 2 2]`. Here we have two parts of size 2. There is a possibility the number `length(v)/n` to be not round. In this case we start with parts of size `n` and the last part is not of size `n`.  Example, `v = [2 1 4 6 8], n=2, idx =[1 1 2 2 3]`. Here we have two parts again but without equal number of elements. Can we do this without for loops?

PS: I hope now that the question is less obscure.

Comment: This probably makes sense to you... I really don't understand what you mean! Could you elaborate more on your input and desired output(s).

Comment: I made some changes, I hope now that the post is less obscure now.

Comment: @Thoth: check your last example, `idx` must be all 1's and 2's, you can't have a `3` in there if you only ask for two parts! So it is either `idx = [1 1 1 2 2]` or `idx = [1 1 2 2 2]` (i.e the extra element gets assigned to either the first or last split). Ignoring that, my code works as intended.

Comment: I would like to thank both `Luis Mendo` and `Amro` for their answer!!++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After question edit:

```
idx = ceil( (1:numel(v)) / floor(numel(v)/n) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```
% allocate indices (initialized with largest index to handle non-divisible case)
idx = zeros(size(v)) + parts;

% number of elements per part
k = floor(numel(idx) / parts);

% fill indices (matrix linearized using column-major order)
idx(1:parts*k) = repmat(1:parts, [k,1]);
```